Does Southernness tilt Southern metropolises and college towns to the right compared to similar areas in Blue America?
James Carville said “Pennsylvania is Philadelphia and Pittsburgh with Alabama in between.”
In addition to the Urban - Rural divide and the education divide - does being Southern add inherent right-wing tendencies?
NOTE:  This question can be answered objectively from demographic and exit-polling data.

The raw data can be found and interpreted visually at https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/upshot/2020-election-map.html

What does Southernness mean? Ex-Confederacy? Slave states? Geographical? Those parts of the South that are traditionally right-wing? Also, I don't know what you think the James Carville quote has to do with it, unless you're counting central Pennsylvania as part of the South. (Carville means that parts of central Pennsylvania are like Alabama.)

For reference, the 2020 popular vote in the 11 former Confederate states was: Trump 26,384,023 (52.8%), Biden 23,185,682 (46.4%), Other 369,447 (0.7%).  (Wikipedia)

The northen boundary of Southernness is where pickup trucks with confederate flags can be seen @StuartF

@StuartF "I don't know what you think the James Carville quote has to do with it" -- I think OP's point is that the quote suggests the possibility that the key divide is urban/rural (since Pennsylvania is not in the South), and perhaps the South is more conservative just because it happens to be more rural. In other words, maybe there's no separable latitude effect, and Alabama is what Pennsylvania would be if it didn't have cities as large as Philadelphia and Pittsburgh.

@SK "The northen [sic] boundary of Southernness..." -- Would that be Idaho or Montana?

Eyeballing geographically localized election results from the 2020 Presidential election, for the most part, major cities and college towns in the South are more left leaning (as indicated by the intensity of their blue tints) than comparable major cities and college towns in the North, where the urban-rural divide is not as stark as it is in the South in the United States.
The places where major cities (e.g. Columbus, Ohio), and some college towns lean more right politically than you would expect are mostly in the Midwest, the Rust Belt, and parts of the Great Plains (like Kansas and Nebraska).
This may be a function of it not being physically or interpersonally as safe to be liberal in the rural and suburban South as it is in the North.
By the way, James Carville's assessment of Pittsburgh isn't that solid (it isn't all that blue for a major city), and the "in between" parts of Pennsylvania are much closer to West Virginia or Kentucky than they are to Alabama (they are culturally monoracial Appalachian, not Southern).

(Map source, no localized data was available when this map was made in the places shown in white.)

"This may be a function of it not being physically or interpersonally as safe to be liberal in the rural and suburban South as it is in the North." - !!!  are you saying the rare southern librul feels safer in big cities and university towns and moves there? @ohwilleke

@SK Yes. That is what I am saying.

What on Earth is "interpersonal safety"?
